# How to map simple database with doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have searched for tutorials on how to make a simple query in Doctine, but there aren't any tutorials for beginners. As far as my understand of Doctrine goes: I only know that doctrine helps you access database: tables, rows, columns by allowing you to store them inside a class, method, properties. What I am **lacking** is how to actually achieve this.

There isn't a simple tutorial everywhere. So, **my question** is, if I had let's say:

**`database: data user: root pass: test`**

```
table: users
     id: username: password: age: email
     01: John      pass1      17   john@gmail.com
     02: smith     pass2      21   smith@gmail.com
```

How can I map these, or how can Doctrine thelp me change this into maps? 
I know this is not a good question, I am just looking for a very simple first guide

Comment: Have you read the documentation at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/ ? It doesn't get much simpler.

Comment: @UlrichSchmidt-Goertz I have, in-fact many times. It's just too hard to get the first time. They don't have simple tutorial. Like, 'hello world'

Comment: @samayo Have you got solution to this. If yes, can you give simple example that you think would be so helpful.

Comment: @cohan sorry I don't have a examples. That was probably the last time I used doctrine. I think for things like these YouTube tutorials are better. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should do a quick read on how Doctrine works, here's a nice tutorial: https://github.com/doctrine/orm-documentation/blob/master/en/tutorials/in-ten-quick-steps.rst

The 5th step will show you how to properly configure your database access options.

In Doctrine, you can either write your Entities in a PHP file (xml and yaml are also supported) or you can map an existing database into Entities, using the command line for a reverse engineering. Here's an explanation about this step: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

You can read this presentation on Doctrine 2 ORM's basics too: http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine2-orm-tutorial/

Comment: A simple example would be so helpful.

Comment: There's plenty on the links I've posted. What do you need as an example specifically? A sample basic project?

Comment: yes a simple basic project without any symfony or yaml stuff would be really helpful as i am struggling to learn doctrine too.